# how to pass array or object in store.load({ params: { } })?

Tags: javascript, php, extjs

```
store.load({
        params: {
            start: 0,
            limit: 1000,
            proc_nm: 'sel_bkng_srch',
            test_parms1: [
                {'parm_val_var1':1, 'parm_val_var1':2}
            ],
            srchStrng: '',
            test_parms2: JSON.stringify(parm_val_var1, parm_val_var1),
            connId: 'AW'
        } ....
```

`test_parms1` and `test_parms 2` are attempts to get some kind of array/object into php as stored procedure parameter without having to individually list them. All of my attempts either end up in PHP as [object object] or only the first value. Thought I had all this working but I was only sending 1 parameter which works perfectly.What is the correct syntax? tia.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` represents array.

`[1,2,3,]` array with 3 elements.

`{}` represents Object.

`[{"as":1},{"asa":2},{"sd":3}]` is an example of array of 3 Objects with key value pair.

Try changing `[ {'parm_val_var1':1, 'parm_val_var1':2}]` As

`[{"parm_val_var1":1}, {"parm_val_var1":2}]` which is basically array of Json object, where each object is having a key value pair.

For the json given below, the elements would be accessed as:
`{"abc":[{"as":1},{"asa":2},{"sd":3}]}`

```
jsonObject.abc.as = 1
jsonObject.abc.asa = 2
jsonObject.abc.sd = 3
```

Please also note that I have replaced ' (single quote) with " (double quote). Its a [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: store.load({
            params: {
                start: 0,
                limit: 1000,
                proc_nm: 'sel_bkng_srch',
                test_parms1: [{"parm_val_var1":1}, {"parm_val_var1":2}],
                srchStrng: '',
                connId: 'AW'
            },

Comment: Welcome Mic, I hope this resolves your problem. If not, feel free to let me know. If yes, kindly accept the answer.

Comment: sorry about guff - trying to put code in  comments, hitting return by rote .... when I format as you suggest, I monitor with FireFox.Firebug.parms tab and it shows "test_parms1 
[object Object]" which might be ok if ff does not expand objects .... but from within PHP, $p = json_decode($_REQUEST['extraParams']); gives nothing,  and $p = $_REQUEST['extraParams']); gives [object object] .... is it possible that everything is getting there ok and I need to work out how to correctly decode in php? I added the extra parm to $p = json_decode($_REQUEST['extraParams'], true); still gives nothing. tia

Comment: Actually, I do not know how PHP can decode this value. But think it like a DOM object. I would sugest that - get the extraParam and then use any json PHP library to parse this json. You can also use Javascript json parsing technique inside a script tag (within PHP). I can give that code, if you need - how to parse json and get value using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
store.load({
        params: {
            start: 0,
            limit: 1000,
            proc_nm: 'sel_bkng_srch',
            test_parms2: JSON.stringify([dnStrng, mtStrng, dtFromStrng, dtToStrng]),
            connId: 'AW'
        }, ....
```

then in php:

```
$proc_parms = json_decode($_REQUEST['test_parms2']);
$procNm = $_REQUEST['proc_nm'];

$proc_parms_ar = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($proc_parms as $val) {
    flog("val = %s", $val);
    array_push($proc_parms_ar,array($proc_parms[$i], 1));
    $i++;
}

$tsql_callSP = "{call " .  $procNm . "( ?, ?, ?, ?)}";

/* Execute the query. */
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_callSP, $proc_parms_ar);
```

This takes the parms list and creates an array that sqlsrv requires with 'parm1,1' defining an input parameter, and then calls the SQLServer stored proc that the ExtJS store requested. The $tsql_callSP needs to be constructed from the parms array so a '?' is added for each parm.